# How to mount an external USB drive on Linux read-only?

Tags: linux, mount, read-only

I need to restore a directory on a Linux ([CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS)) file server from an external USB drive. It's the only copy, and I don't want to risk any of the data being altered on it by some mistake with [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) or whatever.

How can I mount an external USB drive on Linux in read-only, just for the temporary purposes of copying the files off of it?

This is how it looks normally in [/etc/fstab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab):

```
/dev/usblaciexl1        /backup     ext3    noauto,defaults 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mount /dev/usblaciexl1 /backup -o ro
```

should be sufficient.

You can also do (do not confuse `if` and `of`, read `man dd` carefuly)

```
dd if=/dev/usblaciexl1 of=/home/user/backup
mount /home/user/backup /backup
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `ro` to the mount options. Something like:

```
/dev/usblaciexl1        /backup     ext3    defaults,noauto,ro 0 0
```

See the `mount` man page for the (huge) list of other mount options.